# IPv6 data transfer between two connected clients on same modem

Tags: ssh, ipv6, scp

I have a modem which gives its clients public IPv6 addresses. If I scp a large file from client 1 connected to same router to client 2 connected to same router will the data transferred be chargeable, or will it be counted as LAN traffic?

Also can someone please explain to me, if my modem is giving me IP address using a /64 prefix (seems I cannot change this to /56 on modem), can I use another router connected to this modem as WAN, to distribute IPv6 public addresses.

Answer (score 1):

> if i scp a large file from client 1 connected to same router to client 2 connected to same router the data transferred will be chargeable, or will be counted as lan traffic.

Works exactly the same way as in IPv4. If hosts are connected to the modem/router's internal switch, and if both hosts think they are in the same subnet (same /64 in this case), they will communicate directly.

> if my modem is giving me ip address using prefix /64 (seems I cannot change this to /56 on modem), can i use another router connected to this modem as wan, to distribute ipv6 public addresses.

The second router needs its own /64. By default, it will try to obtain its own prefix via DHCPv6-PD from the first router, just like the first router obtained one from your ISP.

If you're lucky, the first router will accept the PD (Prefix Delegation) request from LAN and will proxy it to the ISP. In most cases though, it won't know what to do with it.

Changing the first router to start giving out addresses directly using a /56 would not help. It would only complicate routing, as all hosts would think they're part of one massive subnet, and the second router would need to run NDP Proxy to cope with it. (Which it won't: it's not a standard feature in cheap routers.)

If the first modem/router cannot correctly forward the PD request, and if there are no other ways to convince it to obtain an additional /64 from the ISP, you might have to either switch it to 'bridge' aka 'modem only' mode if possible, or resort to some form of IPv6 NAT on the second router.

Comment: Thanks, Now I have some understanding how it works.